# How to use wordpress post title tag in PHP call to plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, title

I'm using a flickrRSS plugin, and would like to use the search term as the title of the post, rather than a specified keyword.

Here is the code snippet I'm using:

```
get_flickrRSS(
  array('num_items' => 10,
        'type' => 'public',
        'tags' => 'keyword'
));
```

I'd like to change the "keyword" to the wordpress post title.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try `get_the_title()`

```
get_flickrRSS(
  array('num_items' => 10, 
        'type'      => 'public',
        'tags'      => get_the_title() 
  ));
```

Reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_the_title

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure but I believe this will work:

```
<?php
     global $post;
     $ID = $post->ID
     get_flickrRSS(
         array('num_items' => 10,
             'type' => 'public',
             'tags' => get_the_title($ID)
     ));
?>
```